# android gradle mergeDebugAssets

Tags: android, gradle

android project with files in assets, these file need encrypt before generator apk
every times i changed some file in assets, 
i need copy out these file , encrypt ,then copy into assets

what i want is:
keep file in assets not encypt (can edit it conveniently) ,
but file in .apk encrypted
encrypt work do automatically by gradle.build

my basic idea is thad add some task before mergeDebugAssets (or mergeReleaseAssets)
before mergeDebugAssets, i replace all file in file://$MODULE_DIR$/build/assets

code like below

```
task processAssetFile {
    // code : replace file in build/assets 
}
mergeDebugAssets.dependsOn processAssetFile
```

the problem is 
mergeDebugAssets is not available in gradle.build

error log below:
Could not find property 'mergeDebugAssets' on project ':gradle'.

so is there some idea can achieve my goals ?
android studio ver :0.52

Comment: solved 
tasks.whenTaskAdded { task ->
    println 'add task:=' + task.name
    if (task.name == 'mergeDebugAssets') {
        task.dependsOn processAssetFile
    }
}

Answer (score 1):

You can always find the task by its name.
I would also suggest that you want to perform encryption for other build variants (makes sense for release even more than for debug).
This requires a little bit of coding since you need to create a task for each variant, too.
It is best to create those tasks dynamically so you don't forget a variant.
Say you're encrypting with some command-line tool, the code you need to add could look like this:

```
android.applicationVariants.all { variant ->
    String suffix = variant.variantData.name.capitalize()
    Task mergeAssetsTask = tasks.findByName("merge${suffix}Assets")

    Task processAssetFileTask = tasks.create(name: "process${suffix}AssetFile", type: Exec)
    processAssetFileTask.commandLine "path/to/your/encryption/tool",
        "--input-file=${inputFilePath}",
        "--output-file=${outputFilePath}"

    mergeAssetsTask.dependsOn processAssetFileTask
}
```